# How to retrieve policy tags in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, tags, metadata, policy

I want to retrieve all the existing policy tags (tag name, id, description,...) of a project. Is there any table storing the tags metadata in BigQuery for querying? or any approach to get them?

I tried "bq show --format=prettyjson project_id:dataset_id.table_id" but it only shows the tags associated to the columns in a specific table.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the api explorer, you can use the same api's in python code as well or in google cloud workflows.

```
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bigquerydatapolicy/rest/v1/projects.locations.dataPolicies/list
```

and passing below input parameter in parent, provided you have IAM role to access all the policies at project level

```
projects/YOURPROJECTNUMBER/locations/australia-southeast2
```

the response will be

```
{
  "dataPolicies": [
    {
      "name": "projects/YOURPROJECTNUMBER/locations/australia-southeast2/dataPolicies/testRule",
      "dataPolicyType": "DATA_MASKING_POLICY",
      "dataPolicyId": "testRule",
      "policyTag": "projects/YOURPROJECTNUMBER/locations/australia-southeast2/taxonomies/2547889950319510540/policyTags/2252084482334855564",
      "dataMaskingPolicy": {
        "predefinedExpression": "ALWAYS_NULL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.